# Ansible to copy content from stdout_lines into a file and the format is totally changing

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

```
- name: Verify the health of pods
  shell: 'kubectl get pods -n {{NAMESPACE}}'
  register: kubectl_pods1

- debug: msg="{{ ncs_kubectl_pods1.stdout_lines}}"

- name: print to log file
  lineinfile:
    path: '/tmp/sample.log'
    line: "{{ ncs_kubectl_pods1.stdout_lines }}"
    create: yes
```

** Not able to print in the lines everything is printing in form of a single line**

```
ok: [testnamespace] => {
    "msg": [
        "NAME                                                              READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE",
        "secretstore-crdb-sentinel-1                                       1/1     Running     0          47d",
        "secretstore-crdb-sentinel-2                                       1/1     Running     0          47d",
        "secretstore-crdb-server-0                                         3/3     Running     0          47d",
        "secretstore-crdb-server-1                                                 "Last login: Tue Nov  2 20:34:14 UTC 2021"
    ]
}
```

inside the sample.log file after printing the variable
['NAME                                                              READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE', 'ca-mariadb-admin-0                                                1/1     Running     0          47d', 'ca-mariadb-mariadb-0                                              2/2     Running     0          47d', 'ca-mariadb-mariadb-1                                              2/2     Running     0          47d', 'ca-mariadb-mariadb-2                                              2/2     Running     0          47d', 'ca-mariadb-maxscale-0

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you asked for *a line* and so ansible cheerfully invoked `{{ ncs_kubectl_pods1.stdout_lines | string }}` and wrote that to your file

What I suspect you meant to happen was:

```yaml
- name: print to log file
  copy:
    path: /tmp/sample.log
    content: "{{ ncs_kubectl_pods1.stdout }}"
```

Although realistically the *actual* answer depends on what you intend to do *next*, as your question smells like an XY problem, but that code snippet should do what you intended, and then you can ask the followup afterward